# ReferenceError "not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Needless to say I am a begginer (You will probably get it when you see my question).

I installed node 
The code is to create an http server (below)

```
> `var http = require('http'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000' ;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' :'text/html'}) ;
  res.end ('<h1> Hello World Joseph </h1>') ;

}) .listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log ('server Running on http://")' + host + ':' + port)

}) <
`
```

now, I have this code in a file called hello.js
I go to the node command prompt, and I type hello.js

I get the following

```
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:262:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Joseph

Comment: type in `node hello.js` I'm assuming the '<' and '>' aren't actually in your code

Comment: The `\`` at the beginning and end shouldn't be there either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer just to follow up on my comment:

I'm not sure if you put the `<` and `>` or ` in your code for stack overflow formatting or not, that said here is the corrected code, essentially those things need to be removed:

```
var http = require('http'),
    host = '127.0.0.1',
    port = '9000' ;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' :'text/html'}) ;
  res.end ('<h1> Hello World Joseph </h1>') ;

}) .listen(port, host, function() {
  console.log ('server Running on http://")' + host + ':' + port);

});
```

Now to run that code in node, simply go to the directory that contains that file and type in `node hello.js`

Comment: Thank you, yes the < ^ > are not originally in my code, this happened when I pasted in the stackover flow. thanks for your help. Its now working, I was not typing properly in node. I typed node in CMD, enter then hello.js.

Comment: Happy to help, can you mark this as the correct answer? Thanks!